# Best way to handle a MySQL table with millions of records updating and large readings

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table of about 5 millions of records, which are being updated every updated a lot (about 10.000 of them every minute).

From the other side, I have to read that table a lot. Fortunately, I don't need the data of "right now" and I can "cache" it (posible solution based on this below), but no more than 20 seconds old.

That could lead to table locking and I'm afraid of that ... any solution ?

I thought about leaving the table just for updating issues, and make a VIEW to copy all data to a a table dedicated just to be read, but it's a big table and it'd take too much time.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: just how many of those 5e6 records are you having to read/cache in that same minute? because 10k out of 5m is only 0.2% of the table anyways.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems if you're using InnoDB tables; [the reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) says that InnoDB supports row-level locking

Comment: The best approach depends heavily on the nature of the updates (are they one batch update every minute?  individual updates appearing randomly?  something else?)  And the nature of the query load (one row, all rows, recently updated rows?).  However, 200 updates/second is quite reasonable for simple configurations  If you have to handle peak loads 100 times that, then you will definitely need to think about scaling issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things you've not told us about. The structure of the table, the nature of the updates, the database engine, the underlying hardware, the constraints of costs and time, the required ressilliency of the solution, the stating you have already done to try to identify the core issues. This is not an invitation to share this - we [can't advise on capacity planning](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning), describing even the [basic steps for performance tuning](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z3ciBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=lamp%20performance%20end%20to%20end&source=bl&ots=6DIVNXzgG3&sig=GHPScbkAFO7IE0L7Eyp0RzDpsEo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwB2oVChMI7KmyhM2ByAIVBNcaCh0-sQt-#v=onepage&q=lamp%20performance%20end%20to%20end&f=false) goes way beyond the scope of a post here.

I expect people will vote to close this, but I will gives you a few pointers:

1. Build the capability to test the traffic volume and measure the performance so that you're not wasting your time in your tuning efforts.
2. Table locking should only be an issue on myisam not the other engines.
3. Use the handler api to connect to the database, ideally via an event based daemon which can aggregate the updates into fewer logical operations.
4. Pay attention to how you configure your storage.
5. Set up asynch replication to a slave node and do your reads on that.